# Text in tabularx does not stretch over merged cell

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow

I am trying to typeset a CV similar to friggeri-cv, but without the need for XeLaTeX. However, the multicolumn environment (second row) does not stretch the text over the merged cells, but rather only over one. How can I make the text stretch over both cells (i.e. over the whole merged cell)? In addition to that, while there is a cell width specified with p{1.8cm}, the following column starts too early, what do I need to change so that it respects the fixed cell width?
[image]

Basically the outcome should have this format:
[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listliketab}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
\begin{listliketab}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.8cm}Xr}%
    \multirow{2}{*}{\footnotesize #1} & \textbf{#2} & {\footnotesize #3}\\%
     & \multicolumn{2}{X}{#4}%
  \end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}
\vspace{\parsep}}

\begin{document}

\section{education}

\entry{Sep 2016 -- present}{Master studies in Witchcraft}{Hogwarts University}{Magical Potions: Theory, Practise and Future Applications}

\entry
{Oct 2013 -- Aug 2016}{Bachelor studies in Wizardry and Magical Phenomena}
{University of Magic South Azkaban}
{Effects of Valerian Root Extract and Dried Dragon Heart Fiber on Soft Tissue of Unsuspecting Muggles}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how (or where) the `listliketab` environment is defined.

Comment: @Mico I added the package to the preamble, apart from that, nothing is defined

Comment: you have specified that the spaning cell is X wide you want it wider so put `\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep` at start of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listliketab}

\usepackage{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
\begin{listliketab}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{1.8cm}Xr}%
\multirow{2}{=}{\footnotesize #1}   & \textbf{#2} & {\footnotesize #3}\\%
                                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth-1.8cm-2\tabcolsep}}{#4}%
  \end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}
\vspace{\parsep}}

\begin{document}

\section{education}
\entry{Sep 2016 -- present}{Master studies in Witchcraft}{Hogwarts University}{Magical Potions: Theory, Practise and Future Applications}

\entry
{Oct 2013 -- Aug 2016}{Bachelor studies in Wizardry and Magical Phenomena}
{University of Magic South Azkaban}
{Effects of Valerian Root Extract and Dried Dragon Heart Fiber on Soft Tissue of Unsuspecting Muggles}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

Problem is deffinig column type in in  `multicolumn` in your command `\entry`. Instead of X (as mentioned David Carlisle in his comment) you shouild use `p{<width>}` column type. Its width can be calculčate by help of package `calc` as `\linewidth-1.8cm-2\tabcolsep`.

For `multirow` I suggest to use new capability of recent version of this package : option `=`, which consider column width for `multirow` width. Now their content appear in two lines.

**Addendum:**
Considering Bernard comment below you can 
in above MWE delete `\usepackage{calc}` and change multi column cell to

```
\multirow{2}{=}{\footnotesize #1}   & \textbf{#2} & {\footnotesize #3}\\%
                                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.8cm-2\tabcolsep}}{#4}%
```

Comment: No need for `calc`:  with ϵ-tex: with `\dimexpr\linewidth-1.8cm-2\tabcolsep\relax`, it's fine.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for this information. I added it into my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! When I use "=" in the multirow environment, it does not wrap the text properly, though. Every word is moved to a new line, as if the 1.8cm arent enough for "Sep 2016" for example. However, the same happens if I extend the space of the first column to 5cm or more. Is there something I am missing? I'd like the first column text to be wrapped just like in the example in the answer.

Comment: @andynitrox, if you can't repeat result of my answer, than you changed something essential in code.  My MWE, as it is, should give you the same result as I show in the answer.